Visual Studio 2022 Resource Explorer - Add File
Microsoft has updated the Resource.resx file in Visual Studio, and I do not know how to add a file. (This is the update for reference.)
My Visual Studio project has a Rsource.resx file with multiple documents contained within it. The files shown existed before the 'upgrade' to Resource Explorer. When I try to add a new document. I choose the green '+' in the top left.

A prompt opens, and I complete it.

But no new file exists after I choose 'Add'.
Drag and drop does not work either. (Although that did work in the previous Resource file.) It opens the file instead.
Surely this must be super simple, and I am missing something obvious.

I hade same problem today,
Try open Resource file with legacy and add files.
Righ click Resource file => Open With => (Legacy)
Hope this helps,


https://stackoverflow.com/a/78924871/2741974
